# .appendchild no es una funcion

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
var principal = document.createElement('group1');
principal.id="forms";
var txtnombre = document.createElement('input');
txtnombre.type = "text";
txtnombre.name = "Nombre";
var spanh = document.createElement('span');
spanh.className="highlight";
var spanb = document.createElement('span');
spanh.className="bar";
var linknombre = document.createElement('label');
linknombre.text="Nombre de la especie";
var btnAgregar = document.createElement('a');
btnAgregar.href = "#";
btnAgregar.text = "+";
btnAgregar.className = "add";

principal.appendChild(txtnombre);
principal.appendChild(spanh);
principal.appendChild(spanb);
principal.appendChild(linknombre);
principal.appendChild(btnAgregar);

$("#texts").appendChild(principal);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Error `.appendChild is not a function`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En **jquery** es `append()`, quedaria así:

```
$("#texts").append(principal);
```

Comment: Gracias.....................

Comment: si te funciono mi respuesta por favor te agradeceria colocar mi respuesta como correcta, es enla viñeta debajo de las flechitas de los votos gracias